Could not open include file "amplifier.sub"

I don't understand why this file that include my subcircuit can't open be included.


Did you try .inc amplifier instead?

There are directories that LTspice looks into, to find things. You may need to update that list. Names also matter. So make sure the extensions used on disk match with those used in the netlist or in part definitions (edit the definition if need be to check that out.)

thanks but it just changes could not open include file "amplifier.sub" by "amplifier" :)

if I put the extensions I have .asc it tells me this : "unkonw subcircuit called in : amplifier"

which list do i have to update and how do i do that :

maybe do you know how have the .lib or .sub from a .asc

@FranceIssenmann - Hi, On Stack Exchange, comments and answers are different things. You wrote an "answer" but it was actually replying to a previous comment (I think). It was not a solution, so I converted it into a comment for you. || Since you asked the question, then unless you are writing the full & final answer to your own question (i.e. unless you don't need further help & you have solved the problem yourself using a different solution than any other answer) please don't use the box labeled "Your Answer" below.

(cont'd) Instead, use a comment to reply to a previous comment. If you have more info, please [edit] the question (unless that would invalidate an answer). || Please see the [tour] & [help]. || Don't write several short comments. Consolidate them where possible & sensible, since long comment chains often trigger treatment like discussions & may be moved to a chatroom. This might be avoided with good comment etiquette e.g. consolidation. || Finally, do use @replies to address a comment response to a specific user - see here.

Does the file amplifier.sub exist? You don't have file extensions visible but I'd be willing to bet those files are amplifier.asc and amplifier.asy, not amplifier.sub.

What happens if you simply delete the .include statement? If you’re using hierarchical schematics and symbols you shouldn’t need to include anything.
